# Internal resistance of an analog ammeter

Tags: current-measurement

Why does the internal resistance of an analog ammeter decrease as the range used increases? For example say I am using the 100 mA range of a ammeter, if I measure the internal resistance, it is a larger value than when I use for instance the 300 mA range of the ammeter.

Comment: Decrease when the range is doing what?

Comment: More current means more heat for the same current sense resistance used. More heat than you want and more voltage drop (or needle deflection) than you need . BTW this is not a coherent question since you say the range is used but there is always a range in operation when the meter is used. You need to actually say whether the range increases or decreases. I just happen to know what you are trying to ask.

Comment: a bigger drop would equal more power to lift the needle

Comment: The meter needle swings in an amount proportional to the voltage applied to the movement.  To make a higher range, you need to put a larger conductance (i.e., smaller resistance) in parallel with the meter.

Comment: @TimWescott, no, it does not.  It swings proportional to the *current* passing *through* the movement.  The rest of your comment is almost right, in that the  current dividers producing the same result from different input have differing overall impedance.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And the *current* passing *through* the movement is proportional to the *voltage* because the *resistance* of the coil is *essentially constant*.  If that weren't the case, then the current dividers wouldn't work worth beans.

Comment: @TimWescott the point is that it's the current that actual produces the deflection

Comment: @ChrisStratton that is your point, yes.  My point was meant to illuminate and rationalize how one may choose shunt resistors.

Answer (score 2):

A DC analog ammeter is essentially a voltmeter in parallel with a shunt resistor.

It's a bit more complex than that, because a typical (d'Arsonval moving coil with taut band suspension) meter movement actually measures current, and has a resistance that is temperature sensitive since it's typically wound with copper wire rather than an alloy like Constantan or Manganin. In a real meter movement, a temperature-sensitive network such as an NTC thermistor in parallel with a resistor may be put in series with the copper winding to counteract the positive temperature coefficient of the coil, yielding a voltage sensitive movement with perhaps 50uA full scale and a full scale voltage of around 100-200mV.

Then to get different ranges you would switch a resistor in parallel with the (say) 150mV movement that yields 150mV at the full-scale current (taking into account the meter movement resistance and the external shunt).

So in the case of a 150mV burden and 3K meter + network resistance, the shunt resistors would be:

50uA - no shunt

100uA 6.00K

...

50mA - 3.03 ohms

etc.

In this example, the ammeter will always drop 150mV at full scale deflection regardless of what the scale is- so the "internal resistance" of the meter as a whole instrument is **inversely proportional** to the full-scale (full deflection of the pointer) current range.

Here is a photo of the inside of the venerable Simpson 260 multimeter, courtesy of [this](https://antiqueradios.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=293759&start=0) site:

[image]

The disk-shaped object is a thermistor. The 260 used a jeweled movement (tiny bearings rather than a taut band). There's also usually some protection components such as diodes and fuses to help keep the meter and shunt components from being damaged by overloads.